# storing persistent object in asyncStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I do not know if this is possible, but I am trying to store persistent data in async storage, so whenever the array data in the storage key is fetched, that persistent data is always at the top of the array. Also, persistent data cannot be deleted. below is a sample code, and I have shown only the functions for better clarity.

```
      componentWillMount() {
        this.saveData();
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.getDataSync();
      }

      getDataSync = async () => {
        try {
          const list = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LIST_STORAGE_KEY);

          const parsedList = JSON.parse(list);

          this.setState({
            isDataReady: true,
            list: parsedList || []
          });

          console.log(parsedList, this.state.list);
          } catch (e) {
          Alert.alert('Failed to load list.');
        }
      }

      saveData = () => {
        const data = [
          {
            firstname: 'John',
            lastname: 'Doe',
            image: null,
            email: 'john@doe.com',
            key: 0,
            phone: '19191919191',
          },
        ];

            this.setState(
              prevState => ({
                list: [data, ...prevState.list]
              }),
              () => this.saveItems(this.state.list)
            );
      }

      handleDelete(item) {
        if (item.key === 0) {
          Alert.alert('You cannot delete this user');
        } else {
        this.setState(({ list }) => ({
          list: list.filter(o => o.key !== item.key)
          }),
          () => this.saveItems(this.state.list)
        );
          console.log('deleted: ', item);
        }
      }

      handleAdd() {
        const { firstname, lastname, email, phone } = this.state;
        const ID = uuid();
        const newItemObject = {
            key: ID,
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            image: null,
        };

        this.setState(
          prevState => ({
            list: [...prevState.list, newItemObject]
          }),
          () => this.saveItems(this.state.list)
        );
      }

      saveItems = list => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(LIST_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(list));
      };
```

Comment: is this a list of objects or strings?

Comment: it is a list of objects

Answer (score 0):

Add another property to the objects, you don't want to be deleted. [Asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) is persistent by default.

```
{
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe',
  image: null,
  email: 'john@doe.com',
  key: 0,
  phone: '19191919191',
  delete: false, // won't be deleted
},
```

In your `getDataSync` sort the list by `delete` property.

```
getDataSync = async () => {

    try {
      const list = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LIST_STORAGE_KEY);

      const parsedList = JSON.parse(list);

      // items with .delete property set to false, will be at the top of the list
      parsedList.sort((x, y) =>  (x.delete === y.delete ) ? 0 : x ? 1 : -1);

      this.setState({
        isDataReady: true,
        list: parsedList || []
      });

      console.log(parsedList, this.state.list);
      } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert('Failed to load list.');
    }
  }
```

Comment: and when you display your data, check for the ```.delete``` property if it's false don't display the delete button.

Comment: not working.. still same result, applying my code as shown above stores the persistent data, and appends any other new array object added below it, but after two reloads, it deletes the new obects added. thats my main concern